# Applying radius corners to the end of the menu not every item

Tags: html, css, menu

This is my menu -

```
<div ><ul id="menu">
        <li class="one"><a href="http://www.domain.com">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li class="two"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>">Profile</a></li>
        <li class="three"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>messages">Messages</a></li>
        <li class="four"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>friends">Friends</a></li>
        <li><?php bp_adminbar_notifications_menu() ?>
        <ul>
        <li> </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

This is the CSS -

```
ul#menu li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0px 0 0;
    background-color: #F8FCFE;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px 10px;

}

ul#menu li a:link, ul#menu li a:visited {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 88px;
    height: 53px;
    line-height: 53px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    outline: none;
    float: left;
    background: #F8FCFE;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px 10px;
}
```

What I would like is the left item to have top left, bottom left radius and the last item to have top right and bottom right to have radius. So it looks like vertical rectangle with radius corners.

Answer (score 0):

have the first `li` and last one have a different class such as `first` and `last`, first with left top and bottom last with right top and bottom

```
li.first {
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; }

li.last {
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; }
```

the menu

```
<ul id="menu">
<li class="one first"><a href="http://www.domain.com">Dashboard</a></li>
<li class="two"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>">Profile</a></li>
<li class="three"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>messages">Messages</a></li>
<li class="four"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>friends">Friends</a></li>
<li class="last"><?php bp_adminbar_notifications_menu() ?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: remove `border-top-left-radius/border-bottom-left-radius` from `ul#menu li` and `ul#menu li a:link, ul#menu li a:visited`

Comment: I did. Makes no difference :/

Comment: @John B's answer you didn't close the last `li` element after the `<?php bp_adminbar_notifications_menu() ?>` also the last `ul`

Comment: `<ul id="menu">
<li class="one"><a href="http://www.domain.com">Dashboard</a></li>
<li class="two"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>">Profile</a></li>
<li class="three"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>messages">Messages</a></li>
<li class="four"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>friends">Friends</a></li>
<li><?php bp_adminbar_notifications_menu() ?></li>
</ul>` just keep in mind to always properly close opened tags :)

Comment: sorry didn't notice, change `ul#menu li.four {border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;}` to `ul#menu li.five {border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;}` and change last li to `<li class="five"><?php bp_adminbar_notifications_menu() ?></li>`

Comment: Can you put it in a jsfiddle please? I'm getting confused who's code I'm using. please!!

Comment: `<ul id="menu">
<li class="one first"><a href="http://www.domain.com">Dashboard</a></li><li class="two"><?php bp_adminbar_notifications_menu() ?></li>
<li class="three"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>">Profile</a></li>
<li class="four"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>messages">Messages</a></li>
<li class="five"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>friends">Friends</a></li>
</ul>` since the last li does not contain a link it wont have rounded borders, moved it to second, can't find any other way to make it work

Comment: What's the css your using for this?

Comment: Got it. Pics - [link](http://i50.tinypic.com/2meyis1.png) How do I make it inline?

Comment: add `li.two{border-top:2px solid #999; border-bottom:2px solid #999;`

Comment: Your great! Anyway I can add an image in between the menu items?

Comment: it is possible, unfortunately that is one thing I have no idea how to do

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="one"><a href="http://www.domain.com">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li class="two"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>">Profile</a></li>
    <li class="three"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>messages">Messages</a></li>
    <li class="four"><a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>friends">Friends</a></li>
    <li class="five"><?php bp_adminbar_notifications_menu() ?>
    <ul>
    <li> </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul#menu li {
list-style: none;
float: left;
margin: 0 0px 0 0;
background-color: #F8FCFE;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
border-top-left-radius: 10px 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px 10px;
overflow:hidden;}

ul#menu li.one {border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;}

ul#menu li.five {border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;}
```

you can specify the corners per item clockwise like this : top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left.

rectified for copy and paste directly to css.

Comment: The corners of the links poke through when I tested this.

Comment: did you set up a js fiddle?  if the link are poking through, its just a matter of setting overflow:hidden to the li.  in fact i'll edit my answer.

Comment: John B can you rewrite your answer so I can C/P it in? I'm not being lazy, I'm just a complete noob :)

Comment: done.  basically you just add those 2 rules at the bottom and overwrite the other one with the bigger rule at the top

Comment: Doesn't work with the last item - See this pic - [link](http://i45.tinypic.com/vgmpo7.png)

Comment: add a class of five to the li directly after the li with a class of four in your html and then change the css rule to ul#menu li.five{border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;}.  i'll update the answer for c/p

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gHrAp/)**?

I left your HTML unchanged but updated the CSS to:

```
ul#menu li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0px 0 0;
}

li.one a{
    border:2px solid #999;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px 10px;
    border-right:none;
}
li.two a, li.three a {
    border-top:2px solid #999;
    border-bottom:2px solid #999;
}
li.four a{
    border:2px solid #999;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px 10px;
    border-left:none;
}

ul#menu li a:link, ul#menu li a:visited {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 88px;
    height: 53px;
    line-height: 53px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    outline: none;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;

}​
```

Comment: Thanks, the only thing is - <?php bp_adminbar_notifications_menu() ?> isn't been included as a menu option. Don't know why?

Comment: Not sure I follow what you're saying.

Comment: Oh, then just change the rule for `li.four a` to point to the list item that holds your PHP code. Can you add a class to that list item, like class="five"?

Comment: No? Sorry for being a pain! :/

Comment: Sorry, stepped out for lunch. Can you add a class to the list item that has your PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 lets you define style for specific children. eg:

```
#menu li:last-child {
 // some def
}

#menu li:first-child {
 // some other definition
}
```

hope this helps.